# Listar checkbox desde base de datos mediante php y ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli

Necesito mostrar un listado de checkbox desde una base de datos con ajax. Tengo un ejemplo que lista un `select` con datos de la BD pero no encuentro forma de modificarlo para que muestre los `checkbox`.

El formulario:

```
<form role="form" id="agregar" name="agregar" method="post">
    <select name="usuario" id="usuario">
        <option value="" disabled selected>listado</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" >Enviar</button>
</form>
```

El ajax:

```
$select = $('#usuario');
$.ajax({
    url:"conexion.php",
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(response){
        $select.append(response.seleccionUsuario);
        $('select').formSelect();
    },
    error:function(){
        $select.html('<option id="-1">Error!</option>');
    }
});
```

El archivo php que llamo desde ajax:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","tabla");
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló al conectar".$mysqli->connect_errno;
} else {
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
    $jsondata['seleccionUsuario'] = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        $jsondata['seleccionUsuario'] .= '<option name="usuario" id="usuario" value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["nombre_usuario"].'</option>';
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    print_r(json_encode($jsondata));
}
exit();
```

El código anterior me lista a N usuarios de una base de datos en un `select`. Quisiera listar lo mismo pero en un checkbox.

Comment: En ese caso tienes dos opciones: 1. Escribes los checkbox como los quieres en el servidor y lo devuelves ya escrito. O sea, algo parecido a lo que haces aquí: `$jsondata['seleccionUsuario'] .= '<option name="usuario" id="usuario" value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["nombre_usuario"].'</option>';`, cambiando los `option` por los checkbox; o 2. Devuelves tu arreglo JSON a Ajax y, en el cliente, lees el JSON, construyes cada checkbox y luego haces append en el elemento que servirá de contenedor del checkbox. Es mejor la opción 2, para ocupar menos al servidor delegando ese trabajo al cliente.